# TransactionScope with DapperExtensions?

Tags: c#, transactions, .net-core, dapper, dapper-extensions

I want to group multiple method calls involving DapperExtensions functions under a single Transaction, so that I can roll all of them back if any one fails.

This involves calls to pre-existing functions, some of which

- use DapperExtensions predicates, and/or
- use their own connections.

The answer needs to allow for both predicate calls and multiple connections under a single transaction.

### What I've tried

So far I've found two approaches, TransactionScope and IDbConnection.

**TransactionScope**

```
using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{
      // Function calls here
     transactionScope.Complete();
}
```

Although this should be available in .Net Core 2.0 to my knowledge, it does not appear to be supported by the Dapper and/or DapperExtensions calls I am using. Running this gives me the following error:

```
 "Enlisting in Ambient transactions is not supported."
```

I browsed for documentation about whether this is or will ever be possible, but came up empty.

**IDbTransaction**

DapperExtensions' predicate functions seem to support this, but so far, I can't find any examples of the same transaction being used across multiple connections. A few older posts specifically state that this is a "connection-based" transaction approach, so I'm not sure it's possible.

I'm finding that documentation on DapperExtensions is pretty lean, so if anyone can point me toward some references on how its functions handle transactions in general, that would be very helpful, as well!

Comment: Which version of `System.Data.SqlClient` you are using? Seems like this issue is fixed in 4.5.0 https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24282

Comment: @2kay That was it! The project I started with (.Net Core 2.0) came loaded with a reference to SqlClient, but it was version 4.4.0. I went through NuGet to grab the latest and TransactionScope works now. 

Please submit this as an answer and I'll mark accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [issue](http://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24282) was fixed in `System.Data.SqlClient v4.5`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like that.

```
 using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
                {
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    using (var tx = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        var model = await sqlConnection.GetListAsync<T>(transaction:tx);
                        return model.ToList();
                    }              
                }
```